# Can't show console while using VMware HTML Console SDK

Tags: javascript, html, vmware

I have read "VMware HTML Console SDK Programming Guide" and code following that guide, then meet a problem: I can't see my console on web browser.

The guide is in: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/html-console/html-console-sdk-200-programmer-guide.pdf

Here's my code:

```
<script> 

    var url = "wss://my_ip/ticket/my_ticket";

    var wmks = WMKS.createWMKS("wmksContainer",{})
    .register(WMKS.CONST.Events.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE, function(event,data){
    if(data.state == WMKS.CONST.ConnectionState.CONNECTED){
    console.log("connection state change : connected");}
    });

    wmks.connect(url);

</script>


<div id="wmksContainer" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I've changed job